# How to remove space around CheckBox?

Tags: android

I have a CheckBox and a Button above and bellow the CheckBox.
While I'm watching xml file in Design mode there aren't any spaces around CheckBox, so as when I run it on an emulator, but when I run the app on a real device, I get space of about 7-8 dp above and bellow the CheckBox, and around 20 dp between CheckBox and the text on the right.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
```

[This](http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=12bRZlHaGgafrY0GOMFky4EdoDrSbu1) is emulator screenshot, and [this](http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1zoEqs58QuFlPu0VMBAZjvQzbLv1g) is real device screenshot.
Also, I don't know why now there is a space above checkbox in emulator.

Does anyone knows why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Possibly the default style of the device. Try setting the padding/margins etc to override any defaults

Comment: I tried that, I set padding and margins to 0dp, and only checkbox text moved to the left, it was partially behind the checkbox, but spaces were still there, and checkbox didn't moved at all.

Comment: can you provide an image? that will help us all

Comment: A screenshot would help us get a better solution for you :)

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to mke but jus try surrounding the checkbox with relativelayout and use alignParentLeft=true.. See if that works or just use relative layout on the whole

Comment: android:button="@drawable/checkbox" - why do you need this ? That image size could be the reason

Comment: android:button="@drawable/checkbox" is only to set height, gradient and stroke. Why then on an emulator is as it should be, and on a real phone its not?